# Using aws-sdk inside lambda? (AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi is not a constructor at Response)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to use aws-sdk inside lambda but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update();
var DDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-10-08" });


exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
  var url_handler = event.requestContext.domainName + "/" + event.requestContext.stage;


  var scanParams = {
    TableName: "tbl-web-socket-connection",
    ProjectionExpression: "id"
  };

  DDB.scan(scanParams, function (err, data) {
    console.log(err, "Error");
    if (err) {
      callback(null, {
        statusCode: 500,
        body: JSON.stringify(err)
      });
    } else {
      console.log(AWS, "AWSSS");
      var apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
        apiVersion: "2018-11-29",
        endpoint: event.requestContext.domainName + "/" + event.requestContext.stage
      });
    }
  });
};
```

This is what I declaered on the lambda function, but it gives giving me the error "AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi is not a constructor at Response." on the cloud watch.

Did I miss something? Like maybe including the aws-sdk on the lambda function itself?

Edit: Updated to display the whole lambda function

Comment: Found a very helpful article over at Hackernoon with a 'patch' to get around the 'aws apigatewaymanagementapi is not a constructor' error. [Hackernoon - Websockets & API Gateway](https://hackernoon.com/websockets-api-gateway-9d4aca493d39)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of **May 15, 2019** you can run the Lambda as **node version 10.x** and the **ApiGatewayManagementApi** is included in the aws-sdk by default.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/aws_lambda_adds_support_for_node_js_v10/

Answer (score 6):

To those people who have the same problem as me

It looks like that the version of “aws-sdk” available in lambda execution is 2.29 ApiGatewayManagementApi is added in 2.379

That's why it cannot call the constructor.

To solve this problem, I created a layer with the aws-sdk with it and add those layer to the lambda function.