# Access Api Gateway API operation from VPC?

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

I am trying to figure out how to access the Api Gateway **service** API (aka "Manage Amazon API Gateway") from a lambda running in a VPC. Not I'm **not** trying to invoke an resource method in a private API (I'm aware of how to create an `execute-api` VPC interface endpoint), just calling an AWS service method (`get-api-key`, FWIW, using a Python boto3 client). Hope that makes sense, hard to articulate this clearly with so many overloads of "API" here. Current attempts fail with a timeout, so I presume it's VPC-related, but I'm not sure how to provide access. I don't see any obvious endpoint types that would do so. I've seen references to using a NAT gateway for extra-VPC resources, but I'm not clear how (or if) this would apply. **The VPC has a NAT Gateway configured, and the Lambda's security group allows all outbound traffic**, see configurations below. Appreciate any suggestions.

**NAT Gateway Configuration**

[image: NAT Gateway Configuration]

**Lambda Network Configuration**
[image: Lambda Network Configuration]

Comment: vpc lambas have a 10+ seconds cold start, have you increase the lambda timeout to at least 30 seconds?

Comment: Changing the lambda timeout to 300s (max) has no effect on boto3 call timeout to apigw

Comment: Which error do you get? have you replicated the issue by creating a lambda outside of the VPC to see that the VPC is the issue? I had a similar issue accessing the API gateway API directly via lambda, due to the fact I was using an older version of the lambda runtime where it wasn't fully supported:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54781774/using-aws-sdk-inside-lambda-aws-apigatewaymanagementapi-is-not-a-constructor-a/57003361#57003361

Comment: No error at all, the lambda itself times out after 5 minutes whilst waiting for the `get-api-key` request to complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Accessing the [Amazon API Gateway Control Plane API endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#apigateway_region) requires Internet access.

Lambda functions in a VPC can't access the Internet without a NAT Gateway or another type of NAT device.  See [How do I give internet access to my Lambda function in a VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/) ... or provision your Lambda function outside the VPC if it doesn't really need to be inside a VPC.  Provisioned outside a VPC, Lambda functions have Internet access automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the succinct sum-up of the gateway issues. Per updated description above, we already have a NAT Gateway configured, and the Lambda network config seems to correspond to those settings.

Comment: You appear to be misconfigured.  The NAT Gateway must be on a **public** subnet, and the Lambda function must be deployed on **private** subnets whose default route in the subnets' VPC route table points to the NAT Gateway.

Comment: Ah. Missed the last bit. I'll see about moving the lambda, need to understand what else might be impacted. Thanks!

Comment: After moving my lambda to a private, NAT-routed, subnet, everything works as expected. Thanks!